# Area of a square from a shared side with equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, area

Just checking to see if I got this right. I have a problem in which equilateral triangle ABC, shares side BC with square BCDE. I know the area of the triangle is $60\text{ cm}^2$, and I'm asked for the area of the square, where the answer must be in the form $a\sqrt3$. The way I've solved it is:

\begin{align*}
    A &=\frac{1}{2}x\cdot \frac{x\sqrt3}{2} \\
    A &= \frac{x^{2}\sqrt{3}}{4} \\
    60 &= \frac{x^{2}\sqrt{3}}{4} \\
    240 &= x^{2} \sqrt{3} \\
    x^{2} &= 80\sqrt{3}
\end{align*}
As $x^2$ is the area of the square, I've left it there.

Any help as to whether this makes sense would be highly appreciated. Also, apologies if the formatting isn't great this is my first time posting!

Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, the answer is correct and your reasoning makes perfect sense. Try inserting '\' before 'sqrt'. It will improve the formatting :)

Comment: Thank you so much for that! I thought it made sense but kept doubting myself. Awesome I'll try that next time :D

Comment: @Flophil14 If you found the answer to your question, please consider answering your own question and accepting it to removed it from the Unanswered section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative way (the explanation makes it seem long, but all you need is the last line).

The area of a triangle is $\frac 12 ab \sin \theta$, where $a, b$ are any two sides and $\theta$ is the angle they subtend.

In an equilateral triangle every angle is $\frac {\pi} 3$ which has a sine of $\frac {\sqrt 3}2$

So the area of the equilateral triangle is $\frac 12 x^2 \frac {\sqrt 3}2 = 60 \implies x^2 = \frac{240} {\sqrt 3} = 80\sqrt 3$